# ¿Cómo comparar un objeto con un array?

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo un objeto de datos ontenidos desde mi DB. Este objeto contiene entre otros datos un correo electrónico y lo defino de la siguiente manera:

```
{"1":{"id_usuario":"1","correo":"usuario1@conrreo.com","nombre":"USUARIO1"},"2":{"id_usuario":"2","correo":"usuario2@conrreo.com","nombre":"USUARIO 2"},"3":{"id_usuario":"3","correo":"usuario3@conrreo.com","nombre":"USUARIO 3"}}
```

Ahora bien, tengo un arreglo de la siguiente manera:

```
["usuario1@conrreo.com", "usuario3@conrreo.com"]
```

Lo que necesito hacer es, comparar los elementos de el arreglo, con el dato correo de mi objeto y sólo imprimir los datos del o los usuarios que su correo no sea igual a alguno de los del arreglo, de la siguiente manera

```
{"2":{"id_usuario":"2","correo":"usuario2@conrreo.com","nombre":"USUARIO 2"}}
```

He probado con algunas funciones que he encontrado pero hasta ahora no he podido dar con la solución.

Agradezco de antemano si alguien puede apoyarme a resolver mi duda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí la dificultad radica en que en lugar de un array de usuarios, tienes un objeto cuyas propiedades son números. Para solucionarlo usamos `Object.keys(arreglo);` que retorna un array con los números que has usado como nombres de propiedad que identifican al usuario ("1", "2", etc..). Después, `emails.indexOf(correo)` retorna -1 si el correo no está en el array de correos.

```js
var emails = ["usuario1@conrreo.com", "usuario3@conrreo.com"];
var users = {
  "1": {
    "id_usuario": "1",
    "correo": "usuario1@conrreo.com",
    "nombre": "USUARIO1"
  },
  "2": {
    "id_usuario": "2",
    "correo": "usuario2@conrreo.com",
    "nombre": "USUARIO 2"
  },
  "3": {
    "id_usuario": "3",
    "correo": "usuario3@conrreo.com",
    "nombre": "USUARIO 3"
  }
};
Object.keys(users).forEach(function(key) {
  if (emails.indexOf(users[key].correo) == -1) {
    console.log(users[key]);
  };
});
```